# Magento 2 - Set the maintenance mode with the custom page

Tags: magento2, php, html, htaccess, maintenance

I am about to make a server switch for my site https://www.magento2.com from Apache to Nginx and during for this operation i want set up maintenance mode. The server where I want to set up this mode is with Apache and my Magento version is 2.3.5 p1. How can I set maintenance mode and total redirect to my custom page: "maintenancepage.html"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in developer mode but you can style your maintenance pages by simply adding

maintanence.html in your root directory and style it like any custom html page

- You have to be in production mode though it wont work in devleoper mode

See the docs here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html

Comment: For this operation i found it that the easy way for is that changed original index.php with my custom index.php. Thanks for the answer!